# Texture not loading properly on server

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber

I'm using `react-three-fiber` in creating a 3D render by using `threejs` and `react` together. When run locally, all my textures look fine and load properly. But when run on an Azure VM, it shows some parts of the model have like a foily, almost spacesuit-like texture applied instead of the correct texture.

I'm using an fbx model by the way. I've scoured the net and tried possible solutions like checking the network tab and seeing if all the textures are loaded. And they are, with either a 200 or 304 status. Also checked [this](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/solved-texture-not-loading/2661/7) link but I don't seem to have a problem with how the textures are formatted, which are supposed to be PNG.

I'm not really sure what's going on here since it seems to only occur on the server. Any help/suggestion/advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

*****Note**: Here are screenshots of some of my models when loaded on the server:
[image]

[image]

Edit: Here are the expected results:

[image]

[image]

Here's a code snippet of how I change textures dynamically. I load the model as a mesh using `useLoader` from `react-three-fiber`.

```
 const fbx = useLoader(FBXLoader, '/' + productCode + '.fbx')
 fbx.children.forEach((mesh, i) => {

    if (mesh.name.includes("Eva_Foam")) {
        
        if (productCode === 'DW302' || 
        productCode === 'DW305' || 
        productCode === 'DW406' || 
        productCode === 'DW407' || 
        productCode === 'DW306' || 
        productCode === 'DW403' || 
        productCode === 'DW402' || 
        productCode === 'DW309' || 
        productCode === 'DW310' || 
        productCode === 'DW301' || 
        productCode === 'DW308' || 
        productCode === 'DW401') {
            mesh.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ 
                map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(productCode + '_' + productColor + '_Eva_foam_mat_BaseColor.png'),
                normalMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(productCode + '_' + productColor + '_Eva_foam_mat_Normal.png'),
                heightMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(productCode + '_' + productColor + '_Eva_foam_mat_Height.png'),
                metalnessMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(productCode + '_' + productColor + '_Eva_foam_mat_Metallic.png'),
                roughnessMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(productCode + '_' + productColor + '_Eva_foam_mat_Roughness.png'),
            });
        }
    } else if (mesh.name.includes("bottle")) {
        mesh.children.forEach((mat, i) => {
            mat.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ 
                map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(productCode + '_' + productColor + '_mat_BaseColor.png'),
                roughnessMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(productCode + '_' + productColor + '_mat_Roughness.png'),
                metalnessMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(productCode + '_' + productColor + '_mat_Metallic.png'),
                normalMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(productCode + '_' + productColor + '_mat_Normal.png'),
            });

            if (productCode === 'DW303') {
                mat.material.roughness = 0.8
                mat.material.metalness = 0.6
                if (productColor === 'Bamboo') {
                    mat.material.color = new THREE.Color( 0xAD8257 )
                } else if (productColor === 'Walnut') {
                    mat.material.color = new THREE.Color( 0x72432F )
                }
            }

            if (productCode === 'DW320') {
                if (productColor === 'Navy') {
                    mat.material.color = new THREE.Color( 0x677588 )
                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you show us also the expected result

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. There are a dozen possible explanations as to why you're seeing this, so we can only help you if you provide us with an example of your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @Berthur added edits with expected output and a snippet of how I change textures on load

Comment: @LeeMerlas And do your material changes cause this unexpected result? Or do they occur also without your material changes? Have you tried logging textures as they load? Could they load too late? Have you verified that they load correctly (are identical to the textures that load for you locally)? Either way, there is too much going on here, so try to isolate the problem, as Marquizzo suggests.